# How to count instances of a character or number in whole DataFrame?

Tags: python

Let's say i have list of data frames `month[1..12]`, each with 10 rows and 30 columns filled with numbers 0, 1 and sometimes "N".

I have to count number of instances for each 0, 1 and "N" in each data frame. Desired outcome would be something like:

```
month[1].stack().value_counts()

1: 200
0: 80 
"N": 20
```

Unfortunately, above code gives incorrect answer. How would you approach this questions with other methods?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question.  Do you want to get a total across all the `DataFrame`s in your list?  Or just for each `DataFrame`.  In other words, is the fact that you have a list of multiple `DataFrame`s actually relevant to your question?

Comment: Also, you write "Unfortunately, above code gives incorrect answer.", but how?  It gives the correct answer for me.

Comment: I need a count for each individual data frame. It is somewhat relevant as the method i showed gives the same counts for each data frame, i don't know why.

Comment: "the method i showed gives the same counts for each data frame, i don't know why"  What did you do exactly?  If you have a list of `DataFrame`s (or anything) you can get an result for every element in the list in many different ways, such as a list comprehension: `[m.stack().value_counts()]`.  This works for me.

Comment: I agree with @Iguananaut, this is really unclear. The accepted answer is quite poor, I strongly recommend trying to do things the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of approaching this would be to convert the data frame into a list and perform a count function to obtain the quantities of N, 0 and 1. I have build a simple routine to do this:

```
def get_instances(df, instance):
    df_list = df.values.tolist()
    return sum([index.count(instance) for index in df_list])
```

You can then find the instances of `'N'` in `month[1]` for example by executing the routine with the following parameters:

```
get_instances(month[1], 'N')
```

Comment: I actually tested and this was faster on the OP's 10x30 data than simply running `df.stack().value_counts()`.  But I wonder if that holds for larger data...  I agree there is no reason to do this.